# cast eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl to eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$Factory

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have this simple code snippet which throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$Factory
```

relevant code:

```
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
public class Graphe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource.Factory.Registry reg=org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
        Map<String, Object> myMap=reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();
        myMap.put("graphes", new XMIResourceImpl());
        ResourceSet resSet=new ResourceSetImpl();
        Resource res=  resSet.getResource(URI.createURI("My.graphes"), true);//exception here
    }
}
```

the second line is throwing the exception.
My.Graphes is a plugin that I created with EMF and exported it to eclipse host repository. Any help would be so much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you are experiencing is due to the fact that the `getExtensionToFactoryMap` deals with `Factory` as map value, and not `Resource`. It maps the extension of your `URI` to a `Resource Factory` that will create the right `Resource`.

To deal with your issue, you simply need to register the `XMIResourceFactoryImpl` instead of the `XMIResourceImpl`:

```
myMap.put("graphes", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
```